# JQuery loop through tbody > tr getting child elements

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to loop my tbody and get the tr elements values. 
My table example:

```
<table id='table-draggable1' class="table">
  <tbody id="myTbody" class="connectedSortable">
    <tr>
      <input type="hidden" value="1"  />
      <td>Test1</td>
      <td><input class="btn btn-danger" value=" Remove " onclick="removeFromAllocation(this)"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <input type="hidden" value="1"  />
      <td>Test2</td>
      <td><input class="btn btn-danger" value=" Remove " onclick="removeFromAllocation(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <input type="hidden" value="1"  />
      <td>Test3</td>
      <td><input class="btn btn-danger" value=" Remove " onclick="removeFromAllocation(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then using jquery I can loop through the tbody, but how can I get the first input value and the first td text. For example, the first loop I would like to get the value=1 and the text=Test1

```
$('#myTbody > tr').each(function() {
    console.debug($(this));
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Side note: thats an invalid HTML, <input> cannot be a direct child of <tr>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `find` method to get to the child tags you want, and then other specific methods to further get to where you need to go. Here's a good list of all of jQuery's methods to traverse the DOM: https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

`eq` for instance allows you to pick an element by its index within the context you are searching in. https://api.jquery.com/eq/

```
$('#myTbody > tr').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).find('input').val();
    var text = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text();
});
```

A fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/35c1yc10/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `children()` selector of jQuery. Documentation can be found at https://api.jquery.com/children/

Following is the fiddle which might be helpful for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/divekarvinit/8x0yL6aL

Following code does the trick for you:

```
console.log($(this).children().first().val());
console.log($(this).children('td').eq(0).html());
```